# Comparing two tables using groovy script in soapui

Tags: sql-server, groovy, soapui

I need to compare the values of 2 tables in SQL Server. I have created script but the script I've made is only comparing the whole table as one. The one I needed is comparing each row of 2 tables. Here is my script I've made

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.ResultSet
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.sql.DataSet

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQLSERVER01:1433",
            "User", "password", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

resultsA = sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM Bikestores.production.brands"){
temp1=it.toRowResult().values().join(", ") 
}
resultsB = sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM Bikestores.dbo.sample"){
temp2=it.toRowResult().values().join(", ") 
}

while(temp1 != null && temp2 != null){

brandA = temp1
brandB = temp2

if(brandA==brandB){
    log.info "True"
    break
}

else{
   log.info "False"
   break
} 
} 
sql.close()
```

The result of this is False since there is a difference in values. 
I need to compare each row, like I will get 9 results since I have a 9 rows. If you have better scripts please let me know. Thank you.

Edit:

```
Sample data 

Table 1

id|name | check  
1  | abc   | yes  
2  | def   | yes  
3  | ghi  | yes  
4  | jkl  | yes  

Table 2  

id|name | check  
1  | abc   | yes  
2  | def   | yes  
3  | pqr  | yes  
4  | mno  | yes  


Expected Result  
[table1_name][table2_name]: true  
[table1_name][table2_name]: true  
[table1_name][table2_name]: false  
[table1_name][table2_name]: false
```

Comment: For that the `resultset` or sample data of both queries is needed.

Comment: try to write a query which bring 1 row at a time iteratively and then do minus on those query result. and print the value. Dont write a * query which gets everything at one time.

Comment: What if I have a multiple rows? Writing query that brings 1 row at a time is quite hassle.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing your data, but if the tables have id columns, load the records into maps where you can associate id to id. If you just put the data into a list, the order will mess you around.

Answer (score 0):

**My Thoughts :**
 - The right and suggestible way is filtering by sql query itself like `select * from table1,table2 where field_1 == field_2`. u don't need outside computation.

Or If u really want to do it by code. please try to share the sample table data and expected output format. then only we can help u.

**Answer:**
ur code not collecting the results, it just replaces the latest line of `eachRow()`.  This is the modified code :

```
temp1 = []
temp2 = []
resultsA = sql.eachRow("SELECT id FROM Bikestores.production.brands"){
temp1.append(it[0])
}
resultsB = sql.eachRow("SELECT brand_id FROM Bikestores.dbo.sample"){
temp2.append(it[0]) // If u having one column why u getting values list
}

temp1.each{ brandA ->
  temp2.each{ brandB ->
      if(brandA==brandB){
         log.info "$brandA : $brandB : True"          
       }
       else{
         log.info "$brandA : $brandB : False"
       } 
} 
sql.close()
```

**Note :**

- It seems the first query `select * from` not correct. It will provide all column values. (r u aware of this ?)
- I don't know why u r joining all values on a row using `.values().join(", ")` when u r going to compare with `brand_id`. If i guess right `brands` table should have a column as `id` (intuitive).
- I think u r not sure what u r getting. I hope this notes will clarify and encourage u to ask better question.

**Update 1:**

After seeing ur sample, i guess this is what u r expecting....

```
def getResult(query, sql) // method changed
{
    temp = []
    sql.eachRow(query){
        temp.add(it.toRowResult()) // changed
    }
    temp    
}


resultsA = getResult("SELECT id, name, check FROM Bikestores.production.brands", sql)
resultsB = getResult("SELECT id, name, check FROM Bikestores.dbo.sample", sql)

resultsA.each{ brandA ->
  resultsB.each{ brandB ->
        if (brandA.id.trim() == brandB.id.trim()) // condition only for id match
         log.info "[${brandA.name}][${brandB.name}] : ${brandA.name == brandB.name}"                 
} 
sql.close()
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. by the way I have 3 columns every table which is brand_id, brand_name and check columns. i need to compare the value for each column to another table.

Comment: I have used the code you share it really help me but how can i narrow it down with comparing by row?

Comment: @DenniseSermona i have updated my answer.. pls check it may useful

Comment: by using the update one, no output is printed however on the first script you given it was a big help. The output on the first script was comparing one data to all, can you also help me to compare it by row only so I can only receive an output depending on the no. of row I have.

Comment: @DenniseSermona myfault.. i wrongly put `temp.append` instead of `temp.add` inside the `getResult` method. I have changed it and hope it will work.

Comment: yes i also changed that but still the script didn't work.

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sql for class:

Comment: @DenniseSermona pass `sql` as an argument like i have changed ...

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script15.getResult() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [SELECT brand_id, brand_name, check_ FROM Bikestores.production.brands]

Comment: @DenniseSermona pass the sql object in  `resultA = getResult("select * from table", sql)`. Have u passed  **sql** ?

Comment: it did pass but no output is printed so I don't know what seems to be the error.

Comment: @DenniseSermona no error ? or getting error... ?. if no error, **remove if condition line and print all lines** to see which are lines u need to filter...

Comment: i get same results like in the first script.  

    [abc][abc] : True  
    [abc][def] : False  
    [abc][pqr] : False

resulted to 16 outputs, I only need 4 output. It should be comparing by row.

Comment: @DenniseSermona So u need to filter by id `brandA.id == brandB.id` right ?. I have updated my `if` condition which only checks `id`. have a look

Comment: I mean the script i need is to compare each row of the table, it's either by id or by name. I should get only 4 output not 16 outputs.like for example the id=1 should only be compare to only id=1. The script you have given is comparing id=1 to id=2 then id=3. thanks by the way. I am new in using groovy/java script.

Comment: @DenniseSermona i can understand ur task. this is the possible way by script. u need to convolve. u can merge two lists by indices but it is not suggestible. u can get the expected result by SQL query easily. Even SQL also doing this way... Hope u understand.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat straight-forward way:

```
...

List<String> tableA = sql.rows("SELECT * FROM Bikestores.production.brands")*.join(',')

sql.rows("SELECT brand_id FROM Bikestores.dbo.sample")*.join(',').each{
    log.info "$it equals -> ${tableA.contains( it )}"
}
```